# UITableViewController: programmatically autolayout bug on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

I want to have a `UIView` programmatically added to a `UITableViewController` which is using autolayout...

I have the following code inside of the `viewDidLoad` of a `UITableViewController`:

```
UIView *centerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[centerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:centerView];

// Width constraint, half of parent view width
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:0.5
                                                               constant:0]];

// Height constraint, half of parent view height
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             multiplier:0.5
                                                               constant:0]];

// Center horizontally
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];

// Center vertically
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];
```

---

If I now run the app **on iOS 8** all working well:

[image: running on iOS 8]

---

If I run it **on iOS 7**, the app crashes with the following error:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794`

If I set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES`, the app crashes as well with this notice: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it looks like UITableView doesn't support Autolayout on iOS 7. So we have to use autoresizing masks. My idea is to put a `containerView` with autoresizing mask as the tableview's subview and inside that your `centerView`:

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupBackgroundView];
}

- (void)setupBackgroundView
{
    UIView *backgroundContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backgroundContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    backgroundContainerView.frame = self.tableView.bounds;
    backgroundContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundContainerView];


    UIView *centerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [backgroundContainerView addSubview:centerView];

    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                       multiplier:0.5
                                                                         constant:0]];

    // Height constraint, half of parent view height
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                       multiplier:0.5
                                                                         constant:0]];

    // Center horizontally
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:0.0]];

    // Center vertically
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:0.0]];

}
```

Now `centerView` moves when the table view gets scrolled. If you want to have it fixed and the content hovering above, you should use `backgroundView` on `UITableView`:

```
- (void)setupBackgroundView
{
    UIView *backgroundContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backgroundContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

    UIView *centerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    centerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    [backgroundContainerView addSubview:centerView];

    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                       multiplier:0.5
                                                                         constant:0]];

    // Height constraint, half of parent view height
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                       multiplier:0.5
                                                                         constant:0]];

    // Center horizontally
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:0.0]];

    // Center vertically
    [backgroundContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:backgroundContainerView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:0.0]];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundContainerView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line from your code once and build then.

`[centerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

Comment: getting an error: `property contentview not found on object of type FavoritesViewController` - `FavoritesViewController` is an `UITableViewController`

Comment: @Vamshi: He wants to add the view as a subview to the ViewController's view and not to a UITableViewCell

Comment: @Vamshi: still crashing after removing `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` with this error: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`